# Efect in accordion css

Tags: css, gradient, accordion

can someone tell me how I can achieve this effect on an accordion?

[image: 1]

At the moment I only have this result

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Linear gradient mask-image transparency (several different ways to make it). Below is one of the ways.
A helpful source for this is:
[mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image)

```css
.mask  {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,0,0,1), transparent);
  mask-size: 100% 100%;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<div class="mask"><p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p></div>
```